# Working with big amount of drawings in c#

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm writing a program that draws a lot of elements on screen (about 100000 lines with 2 to 30 points). I'm not sure what is the best way to move and zoom these elements. Is there any faster way then moving and scaling all the points and redraw whole image?

Comment: **Any** solution will involve moving and scaling the points and redrawing the whole image.  Some ways of doing this are naturally faster than others.  When you start needing this many objects in a scene at once you're probably best to start thinking about changing frameworks to something dedicated to graphics processing (ie: OpenGL, DirectX, etc).

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Also: How often will the changes happen? Real time? Can you partition the lines into levels? Will you also scale the pens?

Comment: And you can still leverage your C# knowledge if you go with Unity. Look into meshes probably

Comment: I'm targeting Winforms. Sorry for not writing it before. Changes will be performed by user so not very often I assume.

Comment: Without seeing your code, there really isn't anything that anyone can suggest.  There are too many ways you might be trying to solve this problem and it's ridiculous to make us guess what your code looks like.  It's also ridiculous to expect someone to suggest a solution for you based on nothing but a vague requirement.  This rather feels off topic, but if you can produce a [mcve] you might get a better answer here.